# Create JSON in specific format

Tags: javascript, json

I need send a json via post to api in this format:

```
"answer" => {
    "name"=>"Test", 
    "email"=>"test@test.com", 
    "hospital"=>"Hospital Name", 
    "answered_questions_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{
            "value"=>"1", 
            "question_id"=>"1"
        }, 
        "1"=>{
            "value"=>"0", 
            "question_id"=>"2"
        }, 
        "2"=>{
            "value"=>"1", 
            "question_id"=>"3"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the "answered_questions_attributes" data from inputs, the values are true or false and the name of the input is the question ID, eg:

```
<div class="resp_val_div">
  <input type="hidden" name="1" value="1" />
  <input type="hidden" name="2" value="0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="3" value="1" />
</div>
```

I tried the code below, but this only returns a incorrect json:

```
var resp_val = jQuery(".resp_val_div").find("input");
var dados = {
    "name": jQuery("#name").val(),
    "email": jQuery("#email").val(),
    "hospital": jQuery(".answer_hospital").val(),
    'answered_questions_attributes':[]
};
resp_val.each(function(index, el) {
    d = {"value":parseInt(el.value), "question_id":el.name};
    dados.answered_questions_attributes.push(d);
});
console.log(dados);
"answer"=>{
    "name"=>"Test", 
    "email"=>"test@test.com", 
    "hospital"=>"Hospital Test", 
    "answered_questions_attributes"=>[
        {
          "value"=>1,
          "question_id"=>"1"
        }, 
        {
          "value"=>0,
          "question_id"=>"2"
        }, 
        {
          "value"=>1,
          "question_id"=>"3"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i create the first json in this case?

Comment: That's not JSON.  Are you _sure_ that's what the API takes - it looks more like it might be an example of how to create the JSON in some language, perhaps PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an array and `.push()` if you want an object. And don't use `parseInt()` if you want the `value` property to be a string rather than a number.

```
    var dados = {
        "name": jQuery("#name").val(),
        "email": jQuery("#email").val(),
        "hospital": jQuery(".answer_hospital").val(),
        'answered_questions_attributes':{}
    };


    resp_val.each(function(index, el) {
        d = {"value":el.value, "question_id":el.name};
        dados.answered_questions_attributes[index] = d;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is exactly what i want.